# Angular js How to handle HTTP error globally

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

HI all i have 2 question

angular try to handle server $http error globally. so written below code in app.js

```
angular.module('mname',[])
.config(function ($provide, $httpProvider) {
$provide.factory('ErrorInterceptor', function ($q) {
    return {
      responseError: function(rejection) {
          //console.log(JSON.stringify(rejection));
            alert('Error:==>'+rejection.status+"===>"+rejection.statusText);

            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});
```

1) Here I can able to get that alert if 404 error.
But if server through any code error like missing variable or etc... but connection state is 200 .. that time how can i manage?? 
can't come inside this responseError: area .

2) I wrote one method  for dialog factory to display the errors and message as Factory. I can able to include inside the controller to get working. How can use inside   "responseError:" area . (refer above code)

Comment: Why would the server return an error with a 200 status code?

Comment: Server connection is successful. server return some data.. but correct format is JSON..  so the status is 200